# Raspbian Jessie 4.4 - ttyAMA0 pymodbus not working

Tags: serial, raspbian-jessie

I have a python program that works fine with Raspberry Pi 3 and with an older Jessie version.

I've tested Jessie 4.4 version and I got the following error:

> p1 = request1.registers
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'registers'

The code is simple:

```
import pymodbus
import serial
import time
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer


client1 = ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port="/dev/ttyAMA0",stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = 'E', baudrate= 115200)
connection = client1.connect()
request1 = client1.read_holding_registers(0x500B,0x02,unit=1)
p1 = request1.registers   
print p1
```

The UART pins are in state ALT0:

```
  8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |

  10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
```

The `/boot/cmdline.txt` file was modified
also the serial interface was disabled.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

In the Pi3 `/dev/ttyAMA0` is connected to Bluetooth.

You should now (in all Pi) use `/dev/serial0` which is the device on the GPIO pins.

There may be other issues (not least for some unfathomable reason the Foundation decided to turn serial port off by default).

See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: Hi, I've added to /boot/config.txt  enable_uart=1, and ttyS0 was created but i also noticed that the serial interface was enabled. the Tx and Rx are now in ALT5 mode. after many tests i have the same issue: _object has no attribute 'registers'_

Comment: I swear I just used a USB voice modem with /dev/ttyAMA0 using my Pi3 and Jessie Pixel and I got it to recognize AT commands - without turning off Bluetooth. Was that my imagination - or will both work concurrently without issues?